# How to hide other list items when hovering over one list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a unoderderd list with li elements and when i hover the mouse on one element i want to hide the other elements. How can i do this with jquery.

```
<ul class='sidebar-iproducts-ul'>
    <li>IPuzzles</li>
     <li>IPuzzles</li>
     <li>IPuzzles</li>
     <li>IPuzzles</li>
     <li>IPuzzles</li>
     <li>IPuzzles</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28PPs/)

**The JS**

```
$('ul.sidebar-iproducts-ul li').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().css('visibility', 'hidden');
});

$('ul.sidebar-iproducts-ul li').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).siblings().css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

**The STYLE**

```
li{
 display: block;
 width: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: This one works but what i actually want is display none and block instead of visibility hidden and visible. When i use display attribute it does not work keeps blinking

Comment: Hmm, you'll have to treat it in CSS. What's the desired effect?

Comment: The reason why you are getting the blinking effect is because the second you do mouseover, the mouseout is triggered, the only way I could get around it is with the display:block

Comment: @Eliseu Monar What i want to do is when i mouse over one item hide other elements and display a description about that element. with css only i was not able to do that.

Comment: @Jose Vega - Can u plz explain more. i tried with display block and it does not work properly.

Comment: Sure, forget what I said about display:block. I am using the visibility property because that wont trigger the blinking(mouseover/mouseout) issue you are seeing. With visibility I am only making it invisible, with display:none I am in a way removing the element from the DOM and causing the li element to shift to the top and triggering the mouseout event.

Comment: @Jose Vega - Ok Thanks now i clearly undestand the theory. But with visibility attribute when i hover item on the bottom the top items are hidden and the space is displayed. Can u suggest any other solution where i can achieve this.

Comment: How do you want to go back to showing all the items in the list. You can remove the mouseout event and add some other event to remove the description and re-display the list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5168/discussion-between-rakhitha-nimesh-and-jose-vega)

Comment: @Jose Vega - I was hoping to display the list back by using mouse out event

Comment: All though it is working properly when i hover on last element it does not work.  

jsfiddle.net/nimeshrmr/QSLfu

Comment: I think this question has been answered in http://jsfiddle.net/f23zh/, if you have another question it should be place in another question.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $items = $("ul.sidebar-iproducts-ul").children("li");
$items.hover(function () {
    $items.fadeOut();
    $(this).show();
});
```

Maybe it'll help you.

Comment: This solution works but the current item keeps blinking. I think hover event is called repetitively

Answer (score 1):

May be you can write this

```
$('.sidebar-iproducts-ul li').hover(function(){
    $('li').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).css('display', 'block');   
});
```

Comment: But this method has some issues on mouseover. It keeps blinking